# Math.random が上手くできない

Tags: javascript

`Math.random` を使用して乱数を発生しようとしたのですが、コンソールをみたところ以下のエラーが発生してしまいできませんでした。原因はなんでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Math.ramdom is not a function
getOmikuji @ omikuji.html:15
onclick @ omikuji.html:9
```

**ソースコード**

```
<script>
  function getOmikuji() {
    var omikuji = ["大吉","中吉","小吉"];
    // a - n
    // Math.floor(Math.ramdom() * (n + 1))
    var result = Math.floor(Math.ramdom() * 3);

    alert(omikuji[result]);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `Math.ramdom` はつづりが違っていますね。 `Math.random` に修正してみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
こんな簡単なミス、本当にお恥ずかしい限りです。
以後、気をつけたいと思います！

Answer (score 1):

`Math.ramdom` は綴りが違っていますね。 `Math.random` に修正してみて下さい。

---

*この投稿は [@BLUEPIXY さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/10160/math-random%e3%81%8c%e4%b8%8a%e6%89%8b%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment9200_10160) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*